# Keyboard overlays content in fullscreen mode (Chrome Mobile)

Tags: flexbox, html5-fullscreen

In our HTML chat application, the user should have the opportunity to go in fullscreen mode to hide the navigation bar and get a better user experience. We have a simple layout:

```
<div id="chat">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="write">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your message..."/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Our layout is a flex layout:

```
#chat {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
 height: 60px;
}


#messages {
 flex: 2;
}

#write {
 height: 60px;
}
```

If we go to fullscreen and click on the text input field, the keyboard opens and overlays most of the content. So the user can't see the words he is typing in. Without fullscreen mode, everything is working fine.

We request fullscreen on the "body" element:

```
$("body").requestFullscreen();
```

Is there any workaround/fix for this issue?

Comment: In your HTML, the `header` ID isn't closed properly. In your CSS, there are no quotes around `column`. May want to start troubleshooting there.

Comment: Yeah, just fixed that - but still the same behavior.